# Global List is getting updated abruptly while appending during recursive calls

Tags: python, list, recursion, global

I got a problem titled 'Combination Sum' on Leetcode platform, where I need to find all the pairs that sums up to the target value provided as an input to the program.

In the provided code, during the recursive call whenever the target is equal to cost, the list partialsol needs to be appended to the global list result. But after every recursive call whenever this condition is met, ithe result list gets updated and then the partialsol is appended and after the completion of all the recursive calls, the returned result list is empty.

```
class Solution(object):
    result = []

    def findpairs(self, partialsol, candidates, target, cost, start):
        if(cost == target):
            print(self.result)
            print(partialsol)
            self.result.append(partialsol)
            print(self.result)
            print('---------------')
            return
        else:
            for i in range(start, len(candidates)):
                c = candidates[i]   
                if((cost+c) > target):
                    continue
                partialsol.append(c)
                self.findpairs(partialsol, candidates, target, cost+c, i)
                partialsol.pop()
            return

    def combinationSum(self, candidates, target):
        partialsol = []
        self.findpairs(partialsol, candidates, target, 0, 0)
        return self.result
```

Your input

```
candidates: [2,3,6,7]

target: 7

stdout:

[]

[2, 2, 3]

[[2, 2, 3]]
```

---

```
[[7]] #here the result list is getting updated from [[2,2,3]] to [[7]] even before appending.

[7]

[[7], [7]] #here the partialsol is appended but lost the previous list [[2,2,3]] as it is updated to [[7]].
```

---

```
Output

[[],[]] #returned result as empty lists of list

Expected

[[2,2,3],[7]]
```

Comment: If you append the list at the end, you append the reference to that list. E.g. `a = []; b = []; b.append(a); a.append("I want to change only 'a', does it work?"); print(b)` - b changes as well. You need to append the copy. (In my example: `b.append(a[:])`)

Comment: @h4z3 thanks alot...

Comment: No problem. I had the exact same problem when I was learning Java (also in recursive finding of all solutions for the problem! in my case it was n queens on nxn chessboard), so I'm wary of that now that I'm working with Python. :) References can be tricky!